# how to distribute different values to each jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, parameter-passing

Jenkins Cluster has 1-jenkins master , 2-slave node

Step 1)Build-A has to run concurrently in all the slave nodes.

Step 2)Each slave should get some list of values.

(Values in the list will differ for each slave node.)
[ques: how can I pass different list to all the slave nodes?]
Ex:
Slave1 gets list of values [j2, j4, j1]
Slave2 get list of values [j1, j3]

Step 3)Based on some condition status has to be set as locked for each value in the list.

slave1 locks j1 and slave2 should not lock the same j1 again.
[how can I achieve this, any value from the list has to be locked by only one slave node?]

I am new to Jenkins and I want to know how can I achieve step 2 and 3. 
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: why does Build A have to run concurrently for all slaves? I don't think you want Jenkins for this. You should look at a job scheduler

Comment: if we run concurrently, we can process lot of values at the same time with multiple nodes.

Comment: Yeah, when you say the word "process" and multiple nodes. You should reconsider your solution. Take a look at a HTC condor. It will do what you are trying to do. Jenkins is mainly a CI tool (a very good one). Don't try to build a job scheduling tool on top of Jenkins -- although it can do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I will look at HTC condor..actually we are looking for a tool to achieve the above steps...Can quartz schedular do the same thing? because you have recommended job schedular also..

Comment: Yes. Quartz will also do what you are trying to do.